# Detection for of Running Services on Remote Computer using Java

Tags: java, vbscript, service

Is there a way to detect running services on a client machine using Java? I need to detect a specific running application and it's status (enabled or disabled) and execute something on my application once the running service is detected and enabled.

A little research on my part has come to extent that I have 2 options:

1. Applet and use Sigar-API.
2. VBScript to access client specific process via markup language (HTML).

This alone I think could solve the detection of the service, yet the real problem is detecting its status (enabled or disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use system calls to the underline OS?
something like [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6335) but using 'ps'?

Comment: nice link Josmas, I'll see what I can do with the link you posted. Though to answer your question, It is possible to call Operating System Commands through Java, theres an existing Java Api for this to pull-off. Yet that Alone only solves the Service Detection.. the real problem however is getting the status of the detected service.